# Hadoop: Issue with File Overwrite

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Not able to override a file on HDFS with below command

```
hadoop fs -put -f quicktechie.txt Employee
```

Error message says target file already exists.

Anything wrong with my command?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override a file in HDFS. It is purely work on `Write Once Read Many`. So if you want to override a file, first you have to delete old file.